# List view data class based VIEW confuse

Tags: python, django

```
class CoursesListView(View):
    template_name = 'courses/courses_list.html'
    queryset = CoursersModels.objects.all()
    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     return self.queryset
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = CoursersModels.objects.all()
        context = {
            #"object_list": self.queryset #If self.queryset is called, the page will not be updated after refresh
            "object_list": queryset#Refresh normally after calling
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```

I am very confused about this code,When I insert a piece of data into the database,If **"object_list": self.queryset** is called, the page will not be updated after refresh,You must restart django to update the display normally,but when I run **"object_list": queryset** everything is normal . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If `"object_list"`: `self.queryset` is called, the page will not be updated after refresh.

**Yes**, that is because the `get_queryset()` in Django's `ListView` does *not* directly return the queryset, it will return `self.queryset.all()`. Indeed, if we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2/django/views/generic/list.py#L21-L48):

> ```
> def get_queryset(self):
>     # …
>     if self.queryset is not None:
>         queryset = self.queryset
>         if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
>             queryset = queryset.all()  # ← makes a clone
>     elif self.model is not None:
>         queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
>     else:
>         # …
>     # …
> ```

It thus returns a `self.queryset.all()` and this is a `QuerySet` that has *not* been loaded (yet), and thus will, when enumerating over it, make a new database query.

You thus can implement this with:

```
class CoursesListView(View):
    template_name = 'courses/courses_list.html'
    queryset = CoursersModels.objects.all()
    
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'object_list': self.queryset.all()
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```

That being said, instead of starting with a "simple" `View`, you can make use of Django's `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

# work with a ListView ↓
class CoursesListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/courses_list.html'
    model = CoursersModels
```